# Cannot plot model graph with pytorch HiddenLayer - module 'torch.onnx' has no attribute '_optimize_trace'

Tags: python, graph, deep-learning, pytorch

Using the basic test code form hidden layer, I am getting the error in the title:

```
import torch
import torchvision.models
import hiddenlayer as hl
# VGG16 with BatchNorm
model = torchvision.models.vgg16()
# Build HiddenLayer graph
# Jupyter Notebook renders it automatically
hl.build_graph(model, torch.zeros([1, 3, 224, 224]))
```

Versions:
hiddenlayer-0.3
pytorch=1.13.0+cu117
python=3.10.6

Comment: I have similar problem...

Answer (score 1):

I followed error recommendation and changed _optimize_trace to _optimize_graph in pytorch_builder.py line 71. After that It worked correctly.

Comment: How do you account for this issue WITHOUT updating .py files? This seems like a major flaw in the design of hiddenlayer to me...

Comment: Agreed, in the project repository there is even a pull request which fixes [it](https://github.com/waleedka/hiddenlayer/pull/101) however, If you check the project, It is kinda dead so there is little We can do about it except patching those files by ourselves.